# Bidirectional Path Tracing questions

Tags: path, raytracing, trace, bidirectional

I'm coding a Bidirectional Path Tracing for school in C++ and I have some questions (I don't find useful explanations on the web)

1) Why the EyePath has one more vertice ?

2) When I compute the direct illumination during the EyePath creation, do I need to take account of the value of the previous vertice ? I'm asking that because I saw it on a code but it seems weird.

3) I don't understand very well how to connect both paths. Randomly ? Everyone with everyone ? For the moment I connect randomly one vertice with another one.

4) PBRT book implements a contribution according to Eyepath and LightPath length. Do I need to do it knowing that all the objects in my geometry are diffuse ?

5) Are new rays randomly generated in a hemisphere at every bounce ?

All objects are diffuse.

For the moment I get this result with 15 samples.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) Why the EyePath has one more vertice ?
> >     That's the position sample on your eyes/camera. For pinhole camera, it's a fixed point, but for thin len camera with finite aperture, it needs to be sampled.
> >
> > 5) Are new rays randomly generated in a hemisphere at every bounce ?
> >     That's what BRDF for. If you don't care importance sampling, uniform random on hemisphere is the simplest. Anyway, read Monte Carlo sampling chapter of the PBRT book.

I guess you're new to Monte Carlo ray tracing. The bidirectional path tracing is an advanced algorithm based on path tracing, light tracing and importance sampling. So make sure you understand these techniques well before any coding for bidirectional one~

PS: Just found a detailed explanation on the implementation of bidirectional path tracing (9-part series): http://rendering-memo.blogspot.com/2016/03/bidirectional-path-tracing-1-kickoff.html